# Function inheritance with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, inheritance, mongoose

Is there any good way to inherit functions with Mongoose?

Typically, when you're defining your object schema, you attach methods that you want to be able to call to the finished schema like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, felineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  paws: {
    type: 'Number',
    default: 2
  },
  legs: {
    type: 'Number',
    default: 2        
  }
});

felineSchema.methods.countPaws = function () {
  console.log("I have " + this.paws + " paws");
};
```

But if you're doing good object oriented programming, you'll want to instantiate from a base class:

```
var feline = function () {
  this.paws = 2;
  this.legs = 2;
};

feline.prototype.countPaws = function () {
  console.log("I have " + this.paws + " paws");
}

//Define a new kind of cat inherited from feline
var domesticatedCat = function () {
  feline.call(this);
};

domesticatedCat.prototype = Object.create(feline.prototype);
domesticatedCat.prototype.scratch = function () {
  //Move hind leg to scratch an itch
};
```

Objects should typically be implemented like this, to derive from base classes that contain the functionality common to all classes. But the problem here is that Mongoose will not move these functions from the prototype to the methods property if you try to turn this into a model like so:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, kitty = new domesticatedCat()
, kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema(kitty)
, kittyModel = mongoose.model('domesticatedCat', kittySchema);

kittyModel.scratch();    //Error! scratch is not a property of the model!
kittyModel.countPaws();  //Error! countPaws is not a property of the model!
```

Is there any good way to implement inheritance with Mongoose?

Comment: out of scope of this question, you also have to export the function `domesticatedCat`, in order to make a call to this, via `require`

Comment: Scope isn't the reason this isn't working. I was simplifying the question by assuming this was all in one file to illustrate the principle. In my actual code, I am using module.exports and requiring the object in another file to do this, and as far as I can tell, the problem is Mongoose not following the prototype methods. Please let me know if you would like me to paste what I'm actually doing.

Comment: that's perhaps because there is no real inheritance in javascript but rather delegating through prototype chain. If you view it like this - your paws and legs are delegated to parent object but the model is created from child.